# Mpiexec hangs indefinitely when running a python script

Tags: python, openmpi, mpi4py

When I ran a simple python script with mpiexec it hangs indefinitely

> Output of 'which mpicc' : /usr/local/bin/mpicc
>   Output of 'which mpiexec' : /usr/local/bin/mpiexec

```
import os
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
for i in range(size):
    if i == rank:
        print("{} {}".format(os.uname()[1], i))
comm.Barrier()
```

Verified mpi installation
The above is the code used.
Command :

> mpiexec -np 4 python check_mpi.py

Comment: Your python script runs perfect on my system with OpenMPI v2.1.1

Comment: are you sure `mpi4py` was built for the same MPI library ? what if you simply `mpirun -np 4 hostname` ?

Comment: as a side note, your code is unnecessarily convoluted. you can get the same result if you get rid of the `for ...`, `if ,,,` and `comm.Barrier()` lines (and simply `print(..., rank))`